# Which function should be used in angular to handle api post requests?

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to be able to search for a document with its name property matching the string entered into the input from my angular app by consuming the rest api endpoint with a function call that looks like this

```
 exports.idea_search = function(req, res){
  if(req.body.searchTerm){
    Idea.find({name: req.body.searchTerm}).exec(function(err,docs){
    res.json(docs)    
    });
  }

  else{
    res.send(err);
    console.log(err)
  }
};
```

the angular function that makes a call to this controller function on the endpoint looks like this (other variables included for reference)

```
//api.service.ts

apiURL: string = 'http://localhost:3000/ideas'

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }


  public searchIdeas(idea){
    return this.httpClient.post(`${this.apiURL}/search`, idea);
  }
```

```
//search.component.ts
searchIdeas(search){
   this.apiService.searchIdeas(search).subscribe(data => this.idea = data);
  };
```

when i make call the function from the api html template it works but when i call it from the angular app i get these errors

```
POST http://localhost:3000/ideas/search 500 (Internal Server Error)


ERROR 
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 500, statusText: "Internal Server Error", url: "http://localhost:3000/ideas/search", ok: false, …}
error: "error"
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:3000/ideas/search: 500 Internal Server Error"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 500
statusText: "Internal Server Error"
url: "http://localhost:3000/ideas/search"
__proto__: HttpResponseBase
```

I've tried some different solutions such as changing the api function to return a promise by using the .then() method but i had no success.
Im a bit desperate for a solution at this point

Comment: A 500 error is an error in the **server** code. You won't fix that by changing the **client** code.

Comment: @JBNizet do you see anything wrong with the idea_seach function in the api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly this is why you are expecting req.body.searchTerm in your backend, and what you are sending from client is just a string, so your backend doesn't know what "searchTerm" is. Try to send it like this:

```
public searchIdeas(idea){
    return this.httpClient.post(`${this.apiURL}/search`, {searchTerm: idea});
  }
```

Comment: Yes that worked thank you, now I'm getting [Object, Object] returned in the text input  binded to the idea variable

Comment: Can you post your html? input text should be binded to idea, not to {searchTerm: idea} which is an object